# select multiple rows from uitableview and delete

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delete-row

i am displaying a list of items in a tableview.i need to select and  delete multiple rows from the table at a time,any resources on how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your table has just one section.   You can extend this solution to multiple sections fairly easily.

- Add an NSMutableSet member "selectedRows" to your UIViewController subclass that manages your TableView
- in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` toggle the indexPath.row's membership in   "selectedRows", like this:

```
NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:indexPath.row];
if ( [self.selectedRows containsObject:rowNsNum] )
    [self.selectedRows removeObject:rowNsNum];
else 
    [self.selectedRows addObject:rowNsNum];
```

- indicate visually that a row is selected (e.g., set the cell's accessoryType property to UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark), or modify your cell visually in some other way to indicate that it is a selected row
- add a "delete" button to your UI, either in a table section header/footer, your title bar, anywhere, hooked up to a selector called "deleteRows"
- in your deleteRows method, iterate through the selectedRows set, building up an array of indexPaths, delete these rows from your data model, then call (with your preferred animation type):

```
[self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfIndexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

EDIT:
Here's my full didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.   The deselectRowAtIndexPath may be required for correct operation.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if ( self.editing )
        return;

    [self.myTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:indexPath.row];
    if ( [self.selectedRows containsObject:rowNsNum] )
        [self.selectedRows removeObject:rowNsNum];
    else 
        [self.selectedRows addObject:rowNsNum];

    [self.myTableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
}
```

Comment: i have a problem while doing this,i set an cell image to display while i have selected a cell to delete,but this view is refreshed only after i scroll the cell out of view and then make it come back,how can i refresh the cellimage at the sametime?

Comment: You can force a reload of the table view with [tableView reloadData];.   I have had problems updating individual cells in didSelectRowAtIndexPath (visual glitches), again solved just by calling reloadData.   And sometimes, a trick I use is to make a delayed call to reloadData using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay, sometimes that's the only way to get the table "sane" again.

Comment: thankyou, another problem i am facing is that in the above if else condition only the else part is working all the time,pls help,i nslogged and checked there are values in the set ,but the first condition is not working

Comment: I added in the full method in the my answer in an edit, maybe that will help.   The "if" portion will only be called when the row that was selected has previously selected.

Comment: @Bogatyr So while calling deleteRowsAtIndexPaths the array we are supposed to pass is self.selectedRows in this case right?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *arryData1,*arryData2;
@property (strong,nonatomic)UIBarButtonItem *edit,*delete;
@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    BOOL Selected;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.arryData1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"MCA",@"MBA",@"BTech",@"MTech",nil];
        self.arryData2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Objective C",@"C++",@"C#",@".net",nil];

    self.edit=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(edit:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=self.edit;
    self.delete=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:@selector(delete:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=self.delete;
    self.tblView.allowsMultipleSelection=YES;

    }

-(void)edit:(id)sender
{
    Selected=YES;
    [self.tblView reloadData];
}
-(void)delete:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *selectedCells = [self.tblView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    NSMutableIndexSet *indicesToDelete = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in selectedCells) {
        [indicesToDelete addIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    //arrayFromPlist is NSMutableArray
    [self.arryData1 removeObjectsAtIndexes:indicesToDelete];
    [self.tblView beginUpdates];
    [self.tblView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:selectedCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tblView endUpdates];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Remove the row from data model
    [self.arryData1 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [self.arryData1 count];
    }



 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier= @"Cell";

        TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        }
        if (Selected==YES) {
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"trash.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView.image=nil;
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.arryData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.arryData2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }

@end
```

Comment: on edit button click cell image is change and just select multiple rows then click on delete button u will see all selected cell rows is deleted.

Comment: Add explanation to how does this solve the problem in your answer

Comment: it is just an example on question post "
i am displaying a list of items in a tableview.i need to select and delete multiple rows from the table at a time,any resources on how to do this
"