# How to select multiple rows in UITableview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to select multiple rows in `UITableview`. I can select but my problem is when I scroll the `UITableView` there is an automatic selection of particular row.
I am using this code :

```
-(void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];


    } 
    else {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];


    }

}
```

Comment: there is one link explained regarding content..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954393/select-multiple-rows-from-uitableview-and-delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further code is use for the multiple selection in UITableview

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize arForTable = _arForTable;
@synthesize arForIPs = _arForIPs;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.arForTable=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Object-One",@"Object-Two",@"Object-Three",@"Object-Four",@"Object-Five", nil];
    self.arForIPs=[NSMutableArray array];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.arForTable count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if([self.arForIPs containsObject:indexPath]){
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if([self.arForIPs containsObject:indexPath]){
        [self.arForIPs removeObject:indexPath];
    } else {
        [self.arForIPs addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}



- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

For more details regrading multiple selection Please Refer [following link here.](http://sugartin.info/2011/08/19/multiplecheck-in-table-uitableview/)

Comment: Hey buddy......thousand time thanx....you save my lots of time....Thank you so much...

Comment: @Nimit Parekh - how would you go about storing the multiple selections to an nsmutablearray in nsuserdefaults? thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look on the following article.
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/3481-uitableview-tutorial-part-2-a.html