# Edit the tableview rows for deleting multiple rows in Tableview in iOS giving error

Tags: xcode, ios6, tableview

I follow the link 
[select multiple rows from uitableview and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954393/select-multiple-rows-from-uitableview-and-delete)

I write the code in the delete method as

```
(void)deleterows:(id)sender { 
NSArray *array=[selectedRows allObjects]; 
NSLog(@"indexes are::%@",array);
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
 }
```

but it is giving error as  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException`

reason: `-[__NSCFNumber row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9161b50`

Please tell me where did I made mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are targeting >= iOS5 you could simply use:

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

and then

```
(void)deleterows:(id)sender { 
  NSArray *array= [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]; 
  NSLog(@"indexes are::%@",array);
  [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
 }
```

without using the `selectedRows` array at all.

If you want multiple selection only in edit mode, you should set

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

Have a look at [allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing) in the Documentation.

Comment: It gives the error as "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7524c20'
" at [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop]; Please tell me why this happen?

Comment: Did you initialize the array with the following line?

    NSArray *array= [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

Comment: Please post the NSLog output after `indexes are::`.

Comment: for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"------%@",[array objectAtIndex:i]);
        
        NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[array objectAtIndex:i] intValue] inSection:0] ;
        [self tableView:self.tableView commitEditingStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete forRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
        
    }It works like charm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedRows` is an array of NSNumbers. `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` expects an array of `NSIndexPath` objects. The answer you linked clearly states that you should create such array:

> - in your deleteRows method, iterate through the selectedRows set, building up an array of indexPaths, delete these rows from your data
>     model, then call (with your preferred animation type):
>
> [self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfIndexPathsToDelete
>   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

Comment: I wrote the method as  for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"------%@",[array objectAtIndex:i]);
    
       NSIndexPath *indexpath=[[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
              [self tableView:self.tableView commitEditingStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete forRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
        
    }
Then also giving error.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007175-CH3-SW1